Unable to pull any images inside minikube
Whenever i try to start a minikube always get "unable to connect to registry.k8s.io" and even after if i try to install postgres, vault or my images i am getting "ErrImgpull" error.
Environment:
Pc Network : Corporate LAN
OS : windows 11 enterprise
minikube:
minikube version: v1.34.0
commit: 210b148df93a80eb872ecbeb7e35281b3c582c61
Docker Engine
v27.2.0
Docker Desktop:
Current version: 4.34.2 (167172)
Things I did:
docker prune
minikube delete
minikube start
adding minikube ip to the no_proxy or NO_PROXY
Extra debug :
Able to access registry.k8s.io from a hostmachine's browser
ssh into minikube
ping 8.8.8.8 (which is working without any issue)
docker login -u (resulted in error getting to register.xxxxx)
apt-get update (since minikube is on ubuntu 22.04) , Error updating packages
apt-get error : ( Failed to fetch https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate issuer is unknown. The received OCSP status response is invalid. Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: 18.244.61.11 443]
W: Failed to fetch https://nvidia.github.io/libnvidia-container/stable/deb/amd64/InRelease Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate issuer is unknown. The received OCSP status response is invalid. Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: 185.199.111.153 443]
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.)

In your initial description you say "corporate LAN"; does it have some sort of man-in-the-middle proxy that breaks TLS security?

I don't know that but i will check with the IT team

@David Got an update from IT that they are not aware of any middle proxy for it.

I did download certs for registry using openctl and now it is working fine.

As per this Github link

The registry.k8s.io is a Kubernetes
container images registry that behaves generally like an OCI compliant
registry. Since registry.k8s.io is a proxy
routing traffic to the closest available source, you will need
connectivity to several domains to download images. It is also best
for performance to create your own registry mirror.
When you are debugging issues, make sure you run these commands on the
node that is attempting to run images. Things may be working fine on
your laptop, but not on the Kubernetes node.
Make sure to verify DNS resolution, verify HTTP Connectivity, Verify
image repositories and tags and Verify image pulls.

The error you are  facing apt-get update certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate issuer is unknown and suggests that certificate trust issues within the Minikube.
To resolve the issue:
Add the missing certificate authorities to the minikube environment trusted certificates.This helps to allow it to verify certificates from common registries like Docker Hub.
Consider updating your minikube to the latest stable version.
After making changes make sure to restart your minikube.

i am not able to follow the certificate authorities link you have given in ur comment. I also did check with IT team and they said they don't have any certs to share. I have generated local certs using openssl but still not able to fix this error.
